# Distance and initial velocity of the shortest path along a smooth curve in a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesics

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannain manifold and let $p\in M$. Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to M$ be a smooth curve and let $p \notin \gamma([0,1])$. Assume further that for each $t \in [0,1]$ there is a unique (unit speed) geodesic from $p$ to $\gamma(t)$ with initial speed $v(t) \in T_p M$. Is $t \mapsto v(t)$ differentiable? If so, what is the derivative of $v$ (in terms of $\gamma, g, p$)?

Comment: In the Euclidean case, wouldn't $v(t)= \gamma(t)-p$ (in the usual coordinates)? In this case the smoothness of $\gamma$ implies the smoothness of $v$.

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't read the problem correctly.